# How to merge two different master head into the origin repository master head

Tags: git, github

I am the project admin and one of my contributors was not able to generate a pull request for me, which led to this problem.

The `hv65616` is my branch and `aastha1916` is my contributor branch.

And I want that `aastha1916` branch head to get merged to my `hv65616` branch head so that every other contributor can fetch the changes and the project can be developed without any interrupt.

[image]

Comment: Terminology: What you call "my branch" and "branch head" are actually called "forks".

Answer (score 2):

### Note on terminology

What you call "my branch" is correctly called your repository.

On the other hand, what you call "aastha1916 branch head" is a fork of your repository which is also a repository.

Each of these repositories has a branch named `master`. So with this terminology, we can reword your question as "How do I merge the master branch from a forked repository back into the master branch in my own repository?"

## Answer

### From the command line

You can add the other repo as a remote to your own local clone. From the command line:

```
git remote add aastha1916 https://github.com/Aastha1916/SIH-2022
```

I made an assumption here about the URL for their github repo. Double check that it is correct. Also you will need to change to the correct URL if you use SSH instead of HTTPS.

Now you can `git fetch` to pull down their branch. Finally, check out their branch:

```
git checkout -b aashtha1916/master aastha1916/master
```

This gives you a branch with all their work. Feel free to use whatever name you want for this branch. From here, you can do whatever you wish with this new branch, such as push it to your own repo, commit more changes, make a PR, etc.

### From GitHub web interface

Navigate to your GitHub repo. Then click on the Pull Request tab. Click New Pull Request. Then click "compare across forks". Now you can select their forked repo as the "head repository" and `master` as the "compare branch". Then click "Create Pull Request". Now you have the PR that you can merge into your github repo.

Comment: This we have to do be being in the master branch and also the first command is just as similar to git remote add upstream URL and after running the first command it will add one more remote URL to fetch and pull

Comment: @HimanshuVerma No, it doesn't matter which branch you have checked out. And yes, this is exactly the same as adding an upstream remote to your local repo.